# add a task on build time visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, build-time

Is it possible to add a task in visual studio project build time?

My specific purpose is to copy a file and paste it somewhere else. Its a configuration file.
If yes then is there any type of tasks i can add to build time ???

I am using visual studio 2010 (but will love to know about other versions too).

Comment: I think you are looking for `build events` [How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the properties of the project, under the build events tab you can enter pre and post build actions.  You can pretty much run any executable or shell command.